# Header Chunk Size Error for Wav File

Tags: java, audio, wav, chunks

I'am using these methos in order to read wav files: 
http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html

It give me an error at

`WavFile wavFile = WavFile.openWavFile(file);`

```
WavFileException: Header chunk size (48255020) does not match file size (48255020)
```

However it is not always, when I tried to use different wav files sometimes it is not causing any error.

Is it caused from the wav file or openWavFile method, and can I fix this without changing any WavFile codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chunk size must be 8 bytes smaller than the file as the chunk size does not include the header. So in your example where these two sizes are the same, the file is 8 bytes too small.

Comment: How can I change these size.

Comment: I don’t know anything about the source of your broken WAV files, so I can’t give any hint. In case you want to fix these files by patching, the size is store in the bytes 4 to 7 in little endian order. Just see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#RIFF